# Pairwise comparing two sequences (notation)

Tags: notation, number-comparison

Lets assume we have to sequences with equal number of variables $A = \{a_1, a_2,..., a_n\}$ and $B = \{b_1, b_2,..., b_n\}$. I need to compare each value pairwise: $a_1$ to $b_1$, $\cdots$, $a_n$ to $b_2$; and decide if at least one of the values of $B$ is larger than its corresponding value in $A$. It the a way to writte it short mathematically?

Comment: That does not make sense. Sets are not ordered. So you cannot say this is the first element of A and this is the first element of B. You can compare tuples, or sequences

Comment: Do you mean $a_n$ to $b_n$ in the last comparison?

Comment: each a_i and b_i

Comment: Assuming you meant "sequences" rather than "sets", I think you defined your goal clearly.  If you wanted, you could define notation for it but I don't think there's any sort of universally accepted notation already in use.

Comment: @lulu you are absolutely right. I changed the question to sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of two sets cannot be compared as you described even if they have the same number of elements because there is no specific pairing law. So the comparing does not make sense.

I assume $A$ and $B$ are $n$-tuples (sequence) denoted by $A = (a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ for $A$.

Then, the formal expression would be
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
$$
\exists N \in \N: (N \le n \land b_N > a_N)
$$
or simply
$$
\exists N \le n: b_N > a_N
$$
read there is $N$ such that $b_N > a_N$. You can check whether the sentence is true or not from $A$ and $B$.

Comment: We use $\{\}$ to denote a set and $()$ to denote a sequence or $n$-tuple.